# Why doesnt JMS MessageProducer method setTimeToLive or send() work?

Tags: java, jms

I tried to use either of those 2 methods such that the message that I sent via that producer will have an expiration. For instance, I had set the time to live to 5 seconds (5 000 ms) but even after 5 s, after I subscribe I still get the message from the consumer. I wonder why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification says as below,

> When a message's expiration time is reached, a provider should discard
>   it. The JMS API does not define any form of notification of message
>   expiration. Clients should not receive messages that have expired;
>   however, the JMS API does not guarantee that this will not happen.

So its totally implementation specific. Your Publisher/Subscriber should be implemented in such a way to discard the expired messages as per the JMS specification, if not you are bound to receive those messages even after expiry time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're doing something wrong. Try my test

```
    String url = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector(url);
    broker.start();

    ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    Connection conn = cf.createConnection();
    Session s = conn.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    ActiveMQQueue q = new ActiveMQQueue("test");

    MessageProducer p = s.createProducer(q);
    p.send(s.createTextMessage("!!!!"), DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT, 0, 1000);  // ttl = 1s

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    MessageConsumer c = s.createConsumer(q);
    System.out.println("Received: " + c.receiveNoWait());

    System.exit(1);
```

it uses activemq-all-5.6.0.jar, TTL = 1s, you will see that if you sleep more than 1s after you sent the message it disappears from the queue.